# Pass expression to directive

Tags: angularjs

I have a directive, that has another directive in it's template.

```
<nv-select ng-model="from" ng-options="item.name as item for item in from"></nv-select>
```

Here I try to pass along an expression to the `ng-options` of the child directive. Unfortunately that always gives me the following error

```
Error: Syntax Error: Token 'as' is an unexpected token at column ...
```

If I put the expression in the `ng-options` of the child directive's `select`, it works just fine. My `nv-select` directive looks like this:

```
function () {
  return {
    restrict: 'E', // restrict to elements
    replace: true,
    transclude: true,
    scope: {
      ngModel: "=",
      ngOptions: "&",
      placeholder: '@'
    },
    template: [
      '<div class="nv-select">',
        '<select ng-model="ngModel" ng-options="ngOptions" ng-transclude></select>',
        '<span class="icon suffix-icon-down">{{ text || placeholder }}</span>',
      '</div>'
    ].join(''),
    link: function (scope, elem, attr) {
      var select = elem.find('select'),
          copyValues = function (e) {
            if (e.options) {
              scope.text = angular.element(e.options[e.selectedIndex]).text();
            }
          };
      copyValues(elem[0]);
      elem.bind('click', function (event) {
        elem.toggleClass('active');
      });
      select.bind('change', function (event) {
        scope.$apply(function () {
          copyValues(event.target);
        });
      });
    }
  };
};
```

`nv-select` is basically just a wrapper around a `<select>` to enable custom styling.

Do I have to take special considerations when passing along an expression? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Let's see how ngOptions implemented in AngularJS sources. Here we can find regexp pattern for expressions:

```
var NG_OPTIONS_REGEXP = /^\s*(.*?)(?:\s+as\s+(.*?))?(?:\s+group\s+by\s+(.*))?\s+for\s+(?:([\$\w][\$\w\d]*)|(?:\(\s*([\$\w][\$\w\d]*)\s*,\s*([\$\w][\$\w\d]*)\s*\)))\s+in\s+(.*)$/
```

And then

```
    if (! (match = optionsExp.match(NG_OPTIONS_REGEXP))) {
      throw Error(
        "Expected ngOptions in form of '_select_ (as _label_)? for (_key_,)?_value_ in _collection_'" +
        " but got '" + optionsExp + "'.");
    }

    var displayFn = $parse(match[2] || match[1]),
        valueName = match[4] || match[6],
        keyName = match[5],
        groupByFn = $parse(match[3] || ''),
        valueFn = $parse(match[2] ? match[1] : valueName),
        valuesFn = $parse(match[7]);
```

So you can use it or write new.

Comment: Don't understand you answer at all.

Answer (score 0):

There are two things that spring to mind

- ng-options expects a string, which is then parsed to give the relevant bits. You could try putting `ng-options="{{ngOptions}}"` and see if that gets rid of the problem. However you'll probably bang up against point two which is:
- You've created an isolated scope so even if you got the expression working the scope won't have the relevant properties from the expression on it.

If the {{}} trick doesn't work then it looks like you'll have to $compile the template manually once you have access to the original ng-options string (i.e. in the linking function).